# Can't get JSON.registerObjectMarshaller() to create custom JSON in Grails 1.3.7

Tags: json, grails

I would like to include transient properties in my JSON output for one of my classes (Account). The best way for me to do this would be to use JSON.grailsObjectMarshaller() in the Bootstrap.groovy to create a custom JSON structure for my class, however I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code for the Bootstrap.groovy:

```
import grails.converters.deep.JSON
import stocks.Account

class BootStrap {

def init = { servletContext ->

    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Account, {
        println("test")
        def returnArray = [:]
        returnArray['email'] = it.email
        returnArray['test'] = "success"
        return returnArray
    })

}

def destroy = {
}

}
```

Here is my code for the AccountController.groovy:

```
def jsonTest = {
    def account = Account.findById('1')
    render account as JSON
}
```

And here is my output, which acts as if I hadn't called JSON.registerObjectMarshaller() at all:

```
{"class":"stocks.Account","id":1,"email":"ian...","firstName":"Ian"}
```

Things that I've tried, but didn't seem to help:

1. Grails clean
2. Increasing the priority to 1 on JSON.registerObjectMarshaller()
3. Using the regular JSON converter instead of the deep converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of grails are you using ?

It worked for me having the following in Bootstrap.groovy

```
import grails.converters.JSON
...
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Bank) {
        def returnArray = [:]
        returnArray["name"] = it.name
        return returnArray
}
```

The following domain class

```
class Bank implements Serializable {

    String name
}
```

The following code in a Controller

```
import grails.converters.JSON
... 
def jsonTest = {
    def account = Bank.findById('1')
    render account as JSON
}
```

And getting the following JSON back:

```
{"name":"Niko Securities"}
```

Note: I am using only the regular JSON converter in both Bootstrap and the controller, so maybe check you are using the same converter in both places.

Comment: I am using version 1.3.7. You? I'll try that again and report back.

Comment: Using the regular JSON converter worked. I guess you can't use the objectMarshaller with the deep converter. This is unfortunate, but I guess I'll make due.